# There is a error in importing module algorithm and helpers in python

Tags: python

```
C:\alert system activity detection\Monitoring-Human-Movements-and-Automated-Alert-System-for-Suspicious-Behaviour-using-LSTM-Model-main>python fall_detector.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\alert system activity detection\Monitoring-Human-Movements-and-Automated-Alert-System-for-Suspicious-Behaviour-using-LSTM-Model-main\fall_detector.py", line 9, in <module>
    from algorithms import *
  File "C:\alert system activity detection\Monitoring-Human-Movements-and-Automated-Alert-System-for-Suspicious-Behaviour-using-LSTM-Model-main\algorithms.py", line 9, in <module>
    from helpers import last_ip, dist, move_figure, get_hist
ImportError: cannot import name 'last_ip' from 'helpers' (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\helpers\__init__.py)
```

error cause while import form helpers and algorithm for human movement and fall detection in python

```
import openpifpaf
import torch
import argparse
import copy
import logging
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import csv
from default_params import *
from algorithms import *
from helpers import last_ip
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

these in fall detection file

```
mport cv2
import logging
import base64
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from vis.visual import write_on_image, visualise, activity_dict, visualise_tracking , falling_activities
from vis.processor import Processor
from helpers import last_ip, dist, move_figure, get_hist
from default_params import *
from vis.inv_pendulum import *
import re
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter, lfilter
from model.model import LSTMModel
import torch
import math
from message import message, messagewp
```

these in algorithm file

Comment: It's because the `helpers` package installed in `C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\helpers` doesn't have `last_ip`. Why did you expect that it should have it?